# AngularJS - getting error [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=DbController

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a CRUD angularApp but getting weird error under Chrome dev tools.  Below is full error:

```
error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=DbController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
at angular.js:38
at Nb (angular.js:1577)
at ob (angular.js:1587)
```

I tried looking at DbController but I can't seem to find any issues. I will include all reference to DbController.

Index.php

```
<html ng-app="crudApp">
...  <!-- stylesheet and scripts added -->
<body>
<div class="container wrapper" ng-controller="DbController">
...
```

script.js

```
    // Application module
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp', []);
crudApp.controller("DbController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    // Function to get employee details from the database
    getInfo();

    function getInfo() {
        // Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
        $http.post('databaseFiles/empDetails.php').success(function(data) {
            // Stored the returned data into scope
            $scope.details = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.insertInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('databaseFiles/insertDetails.php', {
            "name": info.name,
            "email": info.email,
            "address": info.address,
            "gender": info.gender
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                getInfo();
                // Hide details insertion form
                $('#empForm').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.currentUser = {};
    $scope.editInfo = function(info) {
        $scope.currentUser = info;
        $('#empForm').slideUp();
        $('#editForm').slideToggle();
    };

    $scope.UpdateInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('databaseFiles/updateDetails.php', {
            "id": info.emp_id,
            "name": info.emp_name,
            "email": info.emp_email,
            "address": info.emp_address,
            "gender": info.emp_gender
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.show_form = true;
            if (data == true) {
                getInfo();
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.deleteInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('databaseFiles/deleteDetails.php', {
            "del_id": info.emp_id
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                getInfo();
            }
        });

    };
}]);
```

Please let me know if you see any issue in DBController code.

Comment: probably you have a syntax issue with the controller code, post your complete code

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I added full code for script.js.  Thanks

Comment: can you post the script references too?

Comment: @Sajeetharan, I uploaded all files here:  https://ufile.io/yltse

Comment: There is a small syntax issue in your controller code

Comment: I fixed it and that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You have a syntax problem with your controller definition. This is not correct:

```
crudApp.controller("DbController", ['$scope'], '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  ...
});
```

This is how it should look:

```
crudApp.controller("DbController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  ...
}]);
```

Although, I prefer this one much better:

```
crudApp.controller("DbController", DbController);
DbController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
function DbController($scope, $http) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I updated the code but that did not fix this issue.  I am still getting same error.

Answer (score -1):

I made few changes to your controller and it works with the code you provided

```
// Application module
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp', []);
crudApp.controller("DbController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    // Function to get employee details from the database
    getInfo();

    function getInfo() {
        // Sending request to EmpDetails.php files
        $http.post('databaseFiles/empDetails.php').success(function(data) {
            // Stored the returned data into scope
            $scope.details = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.insertInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('databaseFiles/insertDetails.php', {
            "name": info.name,
            "email": info.email,
            "address": info.address,
            "gender": info.gender
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                getInfo();
                // Hide details insertion form
                $('#empForm').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.currentUser = {};
    $scope.editInfo = function(info) {
        $scope.currentUser = info;
        $('#empForm').slideUp();
        $('#editForm').slideToggle();
    };

    $scope.UpdateInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('databaseFiles/updateDetails.php', {
            "id": info.emp_id,
            "name": info.emp_name,
            "email": info.emp_email,
            "address": info.emp_address,
            "gender": info.emp_gender
        }).success(function(data) {
            $scope.show_form = true;
            if (data == true) {
                getInfo();
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.deleteInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('databaseFiles/deleteDetails.php', {
            "del_id": info.emp_id
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data == true) {
                getInfo();
            }
        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: What changes did you make? How does this help OP find problems?

Comment: The only change I see is the one I already made as suggested by Pop-A-Stash.  The change was ['$scope'] to ['$scope' ... and close it }]);